# How to use methods of a controller inside another in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to use methods of a controller inside another controller. Basically one of the controllers will use doctrine to query and return an array as response, and i want to use this method inside another controller and use this array to write data in a spreadsheet file. I'm starting with Symfony and want to know what's the best and right form to do this?

Comment: Short answer is you don't.  You are perhaps mixing up controllers with the more generic concept of services.  Learning to use services to divide up your functionality is a key part of using the Symfony framework effectively.  Take the time to understand [services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the container service: [Oficial doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html)

```
$this->container->get('controller')->function();
```

See this image:

[image]